# Compute $\mathrm{Aut}(K_2/K_1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $K_n\subset \mathbb{C}$ a splitting field for $x^6-n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ when $n=1,2$. Show that $K_1\subset K_2$ and compute $\mathrm{Aut}(K_2/K_1)$.

The splitting fields are given by $$K_1=\mathbb{Q}(e^{\pi i /3})$$ and $$K_2=\mathbb{Q}(e^{\pi i /3},\sqrt[6]{2}).$$

If I didn't make a mistake, I've already shown that $K_1\subset K_2$.

My question is for the second part. Can I calculate $\mathrm{Aut}(K_2/K_1)$ knowing what $[K_2:K_1]=6$, and then finding $6$ automorphisms between the conjugates of $e^{\pi i /3}$ and $\sqrt[6]{2}$?

If the idea is wrong, how can I do it?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K_2/\mathbb Q$ is a Galois of extension of degree 12 and has Galois group isomorphic to $D_{12}$, the dihedral group of order 12. If you believe the previous sentence, then $K_1$ is a subfield of $K_2$ with $[K_2:K_1] = 6$ so the corresponding subgroup $\mathrm{Aut}(K_2/K_1)$ has order $6$; thus $\mathrm{Aut}(K_2/K_1)$ is the subgroup generated by the automorphism sending $\sqrt[6]2 \mapsto \sqrt[6]2\zeta_6$, $\zeta_6\mapsto \zeta_6$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a homomorphism $\varphi : K_2 \to \mathbb{C}$ that fixes $K_1$ is completely determined by $\alpha:= \varphi(\sqrt[6]{2})$. But $\alpha^6 = 2$ must hold, so $\alpha \in \{\sqrt[6]{2}\zeta_6^i : 0\leq i\leq 5\}$.

Now if $\varphi_i : \sqrt[6]{2} \to \zeta_6^i\sqrt[6]{2}$, then $\varphi_i = \varphi_1^i$, so $\text{Aut}(K_2/K_1)$ is a cyclic group of order 6 generated by $\varphi_1$.